# Usage of nfc tag ACR1251U on raspberry-pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, nfc, raspberry-pi2

I have an NFC tag ACR1251U-A1. I need to use that with Raspberry Pi.

I have installed the driver on Raspberry Pi via this link: http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/6258/ACS-Unified-Driver-Lnx-Mac-110-P.zip

But when I list the nfc devices on terminal by writing "nfc-list", I don't see any device list.

Do you know how can I use it on my raspberry-pi?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC-list does not work to detect the drive NFC ACR, but install driver for ACR et run this program on python but before install pyscan who is libraries for python2 or 3 :

```
    import smartcard.System
print(smartcard.System.readers())
```